# How to use Bootstrap for Responsive Web Design?

Tags: bootstrap-4, sass, responsive-design

I'm new to the web designing and Bootstrap. I want to make my web page(React app) responsive as I'm using bootstrap for my frontend. Do it require for a beginner like me to play with specific CSS Grid specifications or Flexbox? To be certain, I'm looking for the help to make my page accurately responsive. Thanks in advance.

HTML

**my HTML doesn't get fit here due to character limit. So I'm skipping in writing HTML of my page.**

SCSS

```
.Header {
  padding: 0 40px;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.Header{
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
}
.SocialMedia.ms-auto.d-flex ul{
  
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: .25rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.me-auto {
  margin-right: auto!important;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav a {
    margin-right: 3rem;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #232323;
}
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,
  background-color .15s ease-in-out,
  border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia ul {
  margin-right: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia ul li a .Twitter {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  color: #1ea1f2;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia ul li a .Facebook {
  color: #3c5998;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia ul li a svg {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia ul li a .Youtube {
  color: #ff0400;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
.Header .navbar-collapse .SocialMedia .HeadSearchBar li .SearchBar {
  color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.carousel .carousel-item {
  height: 600px;
}
.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    object-fit:cover;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 500px;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 60px !important;
  background-color: pink !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 550%;
  bottom: 58%;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon{
  height: 60px !important;
  width: 60px !important;
  background-color: pink !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
    left: -16%;
    bottom: 46%;
}
.carousel-caption h3{
font-size: 100px;
font-weight: 700;
color: #fff;
padding-bottom: 20px;
display: inline;
line-height: 1.5;
font-family:'Playfair Display';
position: absolute;
bottom: 585%;
right: 25%;
}
.carousel-caption p{
background-color: lightgray;
color: black;
font-size: 20px;
padding:10px;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: -30px;
left: 22%;
}
ol.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  right: 95%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ol.carousel-indicators li{
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.site-aboutUs-container{
  max-width:1140px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.site-aboutUs-heading-paragraph{
  h2{
    font-size: 65px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  p{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  button{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #f63269;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 25rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4rem;
  }
}
.site-servicesBriefing-container{
  max-width:1140px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  .card {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: none !important;
}
}
.site-layout .site-servicesBriefing .site-servicesBriefing-container.container .card-deck .card .card-img-overlay .card-title.h5{
  color: var( --e-global-color-4b8b2d9d );
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: Playfair Display;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: var(--white-color);
    background: var(--primary-color);
    text-shadow: none;
color: white;
position:absolute;
top: 270px;
}
.site-clientTestimonial-container{
  max-width:1140px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.card-img-top{
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.site-clientTestimonial
{
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 60px 40px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
.row{
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y) * -1);
    margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)/ -2);
    margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)/ -2);
}
.site-clientTestimonial-heading h2 {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'playfair Display';
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.row-two{

    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y) * -1);
    margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)/ -2);
    margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x)/ -2);

}
.col-lg-6{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.clientTestimonial{
  background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00000011;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 43px 27px;
}
.clientTestimonial img{
  position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -50px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
.clientTestimonial ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
.clientTestimonial ul.text-center {
  text-align: center!important;
}
.clientTestimonial ul.text-center li {
  display: list-item;}
  .clientTestimonial ul.text-center li h3{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: 3rem;}
  .clientTestimonial ul.text-center li h4{
  color: #3e3e3e;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 37px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'playfair Display';
  margin-bottom: 0;}
  .clientTestimonial ul.text-center li p{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #3e3e3e;
  }
  .site-services-heading h2 {
    font-size: 45px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'playfair Display';
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }
.site-services{
  padding-top: 40px;
  .service-cardDeck{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    .service-card{
      border: none;
      .service-card-title{
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 20px;
      }
      .service-card-description{
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
      .service-card-button Button{
        font-size: 15px;
margin-top: 10px;
      }
    }
  }
}
.site-salonTour{
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #f2cde1;
}
.col-lg-4 ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: unset;
}
.ReactYTPlayer{
  div{
    float: right; 
    width: 640px; 
    height: 360px;
    div{
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
  }
}
.col-lg-4{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
}
.col-lg-4 ul li h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'playfair Display';
  font-weight: 600;
  
}
.col-lg-4 ul li p{

    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 30px;

}
.col-lg-4 ul li a {
    color: #000000d1;
    background: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 21px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 15px;
    &:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
    }
}
.site-blog{
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.site-blog-heading h2{
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'playfair Display';
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.blog-card-title{
  padding: 10px;
}
.blog-card-avatar{
  padding: 10px;
}
.blog-card-author{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  &:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
.blog-card-time{
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  &:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
.forward-slash{
font-size: 10px;
}
.ago{
  font-size: 10px;
}
.blog-card-description{
padding-left: 10px;  
font-size: 15px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.blog-card-continueReading{
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  a{
    padding: 10px;
    color: red;
    font-size: medium;
    text-decoration: underline;
    &:hover{
      color:blue;
    } 
}}
.site-footer{
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  margin-top: 30px;

}
.content-6-left-description{
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.content-6-middle-title h3{
  font-size: 20px;
}
.content-6-middle-description p{
font-size: 13px;
}
.content-6-right-title h3{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.content-6-right-description input{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.content-6-right-description1 Button{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Please access http://192.168.1.20:3000/ for my React app on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to play with any bootstrap native classes. Bootstrap is a mobile first framework and don't need customizations in major cases and your localhost URL will not work on any other device

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is developed to help you and is responsive out of the box. **The way to achieve that is using Bootstrap in the intended way.**

So, instead of overwriting Bootstrap use html structure and classes from Bootstrap. Two simplified examples to explain:

```
// instead of
  button{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #f63269;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 25rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 4rem;
  }
// use bootstrap
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg>My Buttons</button>
(Or use same classes on >a>-tag.)


//instead of 
.col-lg-6{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}
// use bootstrap
<div class="col-lg-6 d-flex w-50"></div>

* NOTE SECOND EXAMPLE: it is just to show how settings can be achieved by using existing Bootstrap classes even that code does not make sense. Setting width to a Bootstrap col leads to conflicts which prevents the correct responsive effect ;-)
```

As Bootstrap is a powerfull framework it indeed is very extensive and need a little bit learning. The best way to start with it honestly is to have a closer look to the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/

Just use prepared elements with it's html structure and classes and to add extra styling by bootstrap classes. They are developped to work/play together.

**Hint:** Of course there are scenarios you need to add extra code ... but they are really rare and mostover not as extensive as done in your code. Most extras can be realized by theming the framework settings the Bootstrap vars and extending the maps.